After Notarization MyApp can’t be opened because the identity of the developer cannot be confirmed
After Notarization of my app using Xcode, my users still have the error message:
MyApp can’t be opened because the identity of the developer cannot be confirmed.

when using the following command on the downloaded app:
codesign -dv --verbose=4 MyApp.app/
...
Signature size=8980
Authority=Developer ID Application: Codebase Media UG (haftungsbeschrankt) (LZ28YRG3Q4)
Authority=Developer ID Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
Timestamp=23 May 2024 at 12:57:49
Notarization Ticket=stapled
Info.plist entries=25
TeamIdentifier=LZ28YRG3Q4
Runtime Version=14.5.0
Sealed Resources version=2 rules=13 files=30
Internal requirements count=1 size=216

We can see the app is Notarized and signed.
I don't understand why I get this message when my users open the app...

This might be a quarantine problem.  If you distribute your app as a zip archive, and the user moves the zip from Downloads to Applications and unzips it, the app will be quarantined.  Whereas if the user unzips the archive while it is still in Downloads, and moves the app to Applications using Finder, then the quarantine is removed.
You may also want to run spctl --assess on your app.

using spctl --assess --type execute --verbose ./MyApp.app is the best way to understand what is going on, thanks for sharing this. The culprit wasn't MacOS Quarantine but zip. The .app was first valid but became invalid when archived. The GUI version doesn't damage the .app when archiving. I still need to find the right option for zip to not damage the .app. I think it has to do with how it manages symlink by default. Any idea?

Try using ditto rather than zip. The command ditto -c -k --sequesterRsrc --keepParent src_directory archive.zip "will create a PKZip archive similarly to the Finder's Compress functionality" according to the man page.
